# How to load Func<T> from configuration file - Factory pattern - Open Closed principal

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, factory-pattern, open-closed-principle

Below is my factory class:

```
public class BulkFactory<T>
{
    private BulkFactory() { }

    static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<T>> _dict
         = new Dictionary<string, Func<T>>();

    public static T Create(string id)
    {
        Func<T> constructor = null;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(id, out constructor))
            return constructor();

        throw new ArgumentException("No type registered for this id");
    }

    public static void Register(string id, Func<T> ctor)
    {
        _dict.Add(id, ctor);
    }
}
```

And this is how I am registering various bulk job to this factory:

```
BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register("LCOUPD", () => new BAT_LCOUPD<BulkLCOUpdateRecord, BAT_LCOUPD_LOG>(bulkJobCode));
BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register("STBILL", () => new BAT_STBILL<BulkStartStopBillUpdateRecord, BAT_STBILL_LOG>(bulkJobCode));
BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register("PLANCH", () => new BAT_PLANCH<BulkPlanChangeUpdateRecord, BAT_PLANCH_LOG>(bulkJobCode));
BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register("CSCORE", () => new BAT_CSCORE<BulkCSCOREUpdateRecord, BAT_CSCORE_LOG>(bulkJobCode));
BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register("CUSTAQ", () => new BAT_CUSTAQ<CustomerAcquisitionTemplate, BAT_CUSTAQ_LOG>(bulkJobCode));
```

In order to follow Open Closed principal I want to store all these register entries into configuration file and wanted to load it back from configuration. So that whenever I add a new bulk job I need not to modify above lines of code.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `FactoryMethod` array:

```
public sealed class FactoryMethod {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Which you somehow read from your configuration file where `Name` is class name you want to register (`LCOUPD`, `STBILL` and so on) and `Type` is in the format required by [Type.GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for generic types:

> TClass`2[TGenericType1, TGenericType2].

For example (assuming a fictional namespace `Ns`):

> Ns.BAT_CUSTAQ`2[Ns.CustomerAcquisitionTemplate, Ns.BAT_CUSTAQ_LOG]

Then you may write this code:

```
foreach (var factoryMethod in factoryMethods) {
    BulkFactory<IBulk>.Register(factoryMethod.Name,
        (IBulk)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(factoryMethod.Type), bulkJobCode));
}
```

Note that I don't know exact type of your classes and prototype of your functions then you may need a cast here or there.

Comment: I just realized that this implementation is utilizing reflection which may impact performance. Is there some way around without reflection?

Comment: No, unless you make things terribly more complicate (for example precimpiling code). However...reflection impacts performance but will you ever notice during startup?